# offset() term in glm() sparkR 2.1.0 ignored?

Tags: r, apache-spark, offset, glm, sparkr

I have been trying to fit a glm (Poisson with log link, to be specific) on a dataset in sparkR. It is pretty large, and as such collecting it and using R's own glm() isn't likely to work. This includes an exposure term which needs to be included as an offset (regressor with known coefficient - 1 in my case). Unfortunately, neither adding an offset term in the formula, nor passing the column name (or the column itself, or a numeric vector formed by collecting the coumn after selecting it) works - in the first case the formula isn't parsed, and in the other cases the offset term is ignored - with no error messages at all. Here's an example of what I've been trying to do (outputs in comments):

```
library(datasets)
#set up Spark session
#Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/usr/share/spark_2.1.0")
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
options(scipen = 15, digits = 5)
sparkR.session(spark.executor.instances = "20", spark.executor.memory = "6g")
# # Setting default log level to "WARN".
# # To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
# # 17/06/19 06:33:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
# # 17/06/19 06:33:40 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
# # 17/06/19 06:34:22 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
message(sparkR.conf()$spark.app.id)
# # application_*************_****

#Test glm() in sparkR
data("iris")
iris_df = createDataFrame(iris)
# # Warning messages:
# #   1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
# #   Use Sepal_Length instead of Sepal.Length  as column name
# # 2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
# #   Use Sepal_Width instead of Sepal.Width  as column name
# # 3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
# #   Use Petal_Length instead of Petal.Length  as column name
# # 4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
# #   Use Petal_Width instead of Petal.Width  as column name
model = glm(Sepal_Length ~ offset(Sepal_Width) + Petal_Length, data = iris_df)
# # 17/06/19 08:46:47 ERROR RBackendHandler: fit on org.apache.spark.ml.r.GeneralizedLinearRegressionWrapper failed
# # java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
# # ......
# # Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse formula: Sepal_Length ~ offset(Sepal_Width) + Petal_Length
# # at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormulaParser$.parse(RFormulaParser.scala:200)
# # ......
model = glm(Sepal_Length ~ Petal_Length + offset(Sepal_Width), data = iris_df)
# # (Same error as above)
# The one below runs.
model = glm(Sepal_Length ~ Petal_Length, offset = Sepal_Width, data = iris_df, family = gaussian())
# # 17/06/19 08:51:21 WARN WeightedLeastSquares: regParam is zero, which might cause numerical instability and overfitting.
# # 17/06/19 08:51:24 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemBLAS
# # 17/06/19 08:51:24 WARN BLAS: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefBLAS
# # 17/06/19 08:51:24 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeSystemLAPACK
# # 17/06/19 08:51:24 WARN LAPACK: Failed to load implementation from: com.github.fommil.netlib.NativeRefLAPACK
summary(model)
# # Deviance Residuals: 
# #   (Note: These are approximate quantiles with relative error <= 0.01)
# # Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
# # -1.24675  -0.30140  -0.01999   0.26700   1.00269  
# # 
# # Coefficients:
# #   Estimate  Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)
# # (Intercept)   4.3066    0.078389    54.939   0       
# # Petal_Length  0.40892   0.018891    21.646   0       
# # 
# # (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1657097)
# # 
# # Null deviance: 102.168  on 149  degrees of freedom
# # Residual deviance:  24.525  on 148  degrees of freedom
# # AIC: 160
# # 
# # Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
# (RESULTS ARE SAME AS GLM WITHOUT OFFSET)

# Results in R:
model = glm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, offset = Sepal.Width, data = iris, family = gaussian())
summary(model)
# # Call:
# #   glm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, family = gaussian(), 
# #       data = iris, offset = Sepal.Width)
# # 
# # Deviance Residuals: 
# #   Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
# # -0.93997  -0.27232  -0.02085   0.28576   0.88944  
# # 
# # Coefficients:
# #   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# # (Intercept)   0.85173    0.07098   12.00   <2e-16 ***
# #   Petal.Length  0.51471    0.01711   30.09   <2e-16 ***
# #   ---
# #   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# # 
# # (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1358764)
# # 
# # Null deviance: 143.12  on 149  degrees of freedom
# # Residual deviance:  20.11  on 148  degrees of freedom
# # AIC: 130.27
# # 
# # Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

#Results in R without offset. Matches SparkR output with and w/o offset.
model = glm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = iris, family = gaussian())
summary(model)
# # Call:
# #   glm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, family = gaussian(), 
# #       data = iris)
# # 
# # Deviance Residuals: 
# #   Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
# # -1.24675  -0.29657  -0.01515   0.27676   1.00269  
# # 
# # Coefficients:
# #   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# # (Intercept)   4.30660    0.07839   54.94   <2e-16 ***
# #   Petal.Length  0.40892    0.01889   21.65   <2e-16 ***
# #   ---
# #   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# # 
# # (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1657097)
# # 
# # Null deviance: 102.168  on 149  degrees of freedom
# # Residual deviance:  24.525  on 148  degrees of freedom
# # AIC: 160.04
# # 
# # Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Note: The Spark version is 2.1.0 (as in the code). From what I checked the implementation is supposed to be there. Also, the warning messages after gl don't always appear, but that does not appear to have an effect on what's going on.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the offset term not used in the glm implementation of spark? If it is the second, is there any workaround to get the same results as having an offset term?

Answer (score 1):

A poisson GLM with response Y and offset log(K) is the same as a GLM with response Y/K and weights K.

Example using the Insurance dataset from MASS:

```
> glm(Claims ~ District + Group + Age, data=Insurance, family=poisson, offset=log(Holders))

Call:  glm(formula = Claims ~ District + Group + Age, family = poisson, 
    data = Insurance, offset = log(Holders))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    District2    District3    District4      Group.L      Group.Q      Group.C        Age.L        Age.Q        Age.C  
  -1.810508     0.025868     0.038524     0.234205     0.429708     0.004632    -0.029294    -0.394432    -0.000355    -0.016737  

Degrees of Freedom: 63 Total (i.e. Null);  54 Residual
Null Deviance:      236.3 
Residual Deviance: 51.42    AIC: 388.7



> glm(Claims/Holders ~ District + Group + Age, data=Insurance, family=quasipoisson, weights=Holders)

Call:  glm(formula = Claims/Holders ~ District + Group + Age, family = quasipoisson, 
    data = Insurance, weights = Holders)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    District2    District3    District4      Group.L      Group.Q      Group.C        Age.L        Age.Q        Age.C  
  -1.810508     0.025868     0.038524     0.234205     0.429708     0.004632    -0.029294    -0.394432    -0.000355    -0.016737  

Degrees of Freedom: 63 Total (i.e. Null);  54 Residual
Null Deviance:      236.3 
Residual Deviance: 51.42    AIC: NA
```

(The `quasipoisson` family is to shut R up about the non-integral values detected for the response.)

This technique should be usable with Spark's GLM implementation as well.

See also [a similar question on stats.SE.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66791/where-does-the-offset-go-in-poisson-negative-binomial-regression/66878#66878)

Comment: This should work, but not if you use `glm`. I already upvoted, but would you mind adding SparkR solution `spark.glm` and `weightCol` instead of `weight`.

Comment: @zero323 I haven't used Spark's GLM implementation. Feel free to add the necessary info.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with SparkR:
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: glm_6fa65f4a1164 parameter family given invalid value quasipoisson.

Comment: This is the important bit: "A poisson GLM with response Y and offset log(K) is the same as a GLM with response Y/K and weights K."